# coreplot:Converted coordinates, have problems. [plotSpace plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:point];

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

i want to Convert the point which touch to CPTXYPlotSpace point.but i find there have Offset with real coordinates。
I find ,it Calculated part of the x-axis from the border.
i want to get the point mapped to the value of the x&y axis.

my Enlish is poor....
i want to konw where wrong? please tell me .

this is the code.

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{    NSDecimal plotPoint[2]; 
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    [plotSpace plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:point]; 


   //HERE HAVE SOME OFFSET. I FIND ,it Calculated part of the x-axis from the border
    NSLog(@"touch plotPoint = %d, %f", 
    [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:plotPoint[CPTCoordinateX]] intValue],
    [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY]] doubleValue]);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the point to the coordinate system of the plot area first:

```
CGPoint plotAreaPoint = [graph convertPoint:point toLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];
[plotSpace plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:plotAreaPoint];
```

Comment: Just for the record, this method is deprecated in 2.0